# Copiar texto a portapapeles en javascript

Tags: javascript

Intento copiar una variable string al portapapeles pero no hay manera. Todos los ejemplso que veo son con un botón pero no es lo que intento realizar, y sobre esos ejemplos no me funciona nada. Quiero que al entrar a la web recoja un dato de una variable que es un string, y lo copie al portapapeles

```
<script>
    var copy = "prueba";
    copy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Porqué razón quieres que se copie en el portapapeles? ¿Qué pretendes lograr con esto?

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr que al presionar un botón, por ejemplo, se copie un texto al cortapapeles se usar un par de métodos como `createRange` , `getSelection` y más. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo. Te recomiendo buscar información acerca de ello.

```js
const answer = document.getElementById("copyResult");
const copy   = document.getElementById("copyButton");
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = document.createRange();
const textToCopy = document.getElementById("textToCopy")

copy.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    range.selectNodeContents(textToCopy);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    if(successful){
      answer.innerHTML = 'Copiado!';
    } else {
      answer.innerHTML = 'No se pudo copiar!';  
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
});
```

```html
<div id="textToCopy">
  Copia este texto!
</div>
<button id="copyButton">Click para copiar</button> <span id="copyResult"></span>
```

**Extra:**
Para copiar el dato que se encuentra en una variable es lo mismo. Lo único que cambia es que en vez de recoger el dato del valor de un div, lo recoges de una variable.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes ejecutar el comando `document.execCommand('copy');` al cargar la pagina, este comando necesita forzosamente de un evento disparado por el usuario. te recomiendo ver el siguiente video que puede ayudarte a solucionar tu problema: [COPIAR EL CONTENIDO DE UN ELEMENTO AL PORTAPAPELES - VANILLA JAVA SCRIPT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrUMMMwCH9Q)